# How disable bash to add extra quote in start and end of file in printf function?

Tags: php, bash

I am running this line in various server with various configuration:

```
<?php shell_exec("printf \"Hello World\" > result.txt");
```

In some servers the **result.txt** will have:

```
Hello World
```

But in others, I get:

```
"Hello World"
```

How can I prevent bash to add the double quote?

Comment: Please be more specific about how to reproduce the problem. In exactly which bash versions do you get the latter output with quotes?

Comment: @merlin2011 This is the problem. I don't know. I am running in various bash from various system. Some I get the normal answer, another I get with the quote.

Comment: @Rodrigo: I can't think of any version of shell, where your example could print with double-quotes.

Comment: Give a minimal reproducible example. You mention php functions, so give the full (minimal) way to reproduce your problem, including the php code.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf  I did it. Just run a shell_exec() in servers with random configurations. I really get two outputs for the same command!

Comment: @Rodrigo use http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php

Comment: Are these different servers running different versions of PHP? (And I would more readily presume PHP sends `printf \"Hello World\" > result.txt` than bash has a quote parsing bug.)

Comment: @bishop, yes, various php version! I will need try to check and if fail, do in some other way.

Comment: Thanks @Rahul. But I want to solve it in bash way. This add one more php function. I think I will have to get information about system and try with different style.

Comment: @bishop I don't think PHP Is likely to have that bad a quote parsing bug either.

Comment: Let's give it a shot without escaping: `<?php shell_exec('printf "Hello World" > result.txt');`

Answer (score 0):

Just don't wrap it in quotes? Escape the space instead.

```
<?php shell_exec("printf Hello\ World > result.txt");
```

Comment: This was a good idea, but unfortunately didn't work for all sites. Some yes, others not. Maybe there aren't one solution for all.

Comment: @Rodrigo what version of linux, bash, and php are being run on the sites where it doesn't work?

Comment: Yup, seems to work the same with one or two backslashes. My mistake!

Answer (score 0):

We can further simplify the command so that no quotes are needed:

```
<?php shell_exec("echo Hello World > result.txt");
```